# Asymptotics of sum of Binomial Coefficients (Binomial distribution) - Poisson approximation?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients, approximation

Let $$f(n):=\sum_{i=k}^n {n \choose i } p^i (1-p)^{n-i}$$ where $k\geq 2$ is a fixed Parameter and $p=p(n) \in (0,1]$ depends on $n$ where $np\leq 1$. We consider $n \rightarrow \infty$.

I've found the following Derivation of an asymptotic Approximation of $f$, but I have no idea how to get to this:

$$f(n)={n \choose k} p^k (1+O(np))=\frac{(np)^k}{k!}(1+O(np+n^{-1}))$$

A hint might be that one can approximate the binomial coefficient by the poisson probability $$\hat{f}(n)=\sum_{i=k}^{\infty} \frac{(np)^i}{i!}e^{-np}$$ where $|f(n)-\hat{f}(n)|<p$ and $\hat{f}(n)$ is asymptotically distributed like $\frac{(np)^k}{k!}$.
If this Approximation is used, then I'd also like to know how one get to this asymptotic behavior  $\frac{(np)^k}{k!}$ of the poisson.

A further hint might be on [this site](http://aofa.cs.princeton.edu/40asymptotic/) where it is written that $${n \choose i}p^i (1-p)^{n-i}= \frac{(np)^i e^{-np}}{i!}+o(1)$$ but even with this I am stuck.

I'm really stuck with each of the equations, I can't derive any of them. So I would really appreciate any hint.

Comment: If $k$ and $p$ are fixed and $np \le 1$, there is nothing left to go to $\infty$.  How can you talk about asymptotics?

Comment: Ok I see. Thank you for pointing that out. Let $k$ be fixed, and let $p=p(n)$ depend on $n$, but such that $p(n)n\leq 1$.

it would be even better, if we don't Need the assumption that $p(n) n \leq 1$ but I think one Needs that to prove the above Statement.

I've edited the original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every Bernoulli random variable $X$ with parameter $p$ there exists some Poisson random variable $Y$ with parameter $p$ such that $$P(X\ne Y)\leqslant p(1-\mathrm e^{-p})\leqslant p^2.$$ Thus, for every binomial random variable $S$ with parameter $(n,p)$ there exists some Poisson random variable $Z$ with parameter $np$ such that $$P(S\ne Z)\leqslant np^2.
$$
In particular, for every $k$,
$f(n)=P(S\geqslant k)$ and $\hat f(n)=P(Z\geqslant k)$ are such that $|f(n)-\hat f(n)|\leqslant np^2$.

Furthermore, $\hat f(n)=\dfrac{(np)^k}{k!}g(n)$ where
$$
g(n)=\mathrm e^{-np}\sum_{i\geqslant k}(np)^{i-k}\frac{k!}{(k+i)!},
$$
hence
$$
\mathrm e^{-np}\leqslant g(n)\leqslant\sum_{i\geqslant k}(np)^{i-k}=\frac1{1-np}.
$$
These bounds are nonasymptotic and valid for every $(n,p,k)$ such that $np\lt1$. Do these imply the asymptotics you are interested in?

For the approximation result mentioned in this answer, see R. J. Serfling, *Some Elementary Results on Poisson Approximation in a Sequence of Bernoulli Trials* (1976), freely available as [preprint M374](http://stat.fsu.edu/techreports/M374.pdf) on this [Tech Reports page](http://stat.fsu.edu/techreports.php).

**Edit:** An improvement of the upper bound of $g(n)$, which might help the OP, is
$$
g(n)\leqslant\mathrm e^{-np}\sum_{i\geqslant k}\frac{(np)^{i-k}}{(k+1)^{i-k}}=\frac{\mathrm e^{-np}}{1-\frac{np}{k+1}}.
$$
Once the idea is understood, one can play with these bounds, and with their variants, for example, for every $(n,p,k)$ such that $np\lt1$,
$$
1-np\leqslant g(n)\leqslant1-c(k)np,
$$
where $c(k)\to1$ when $k\to\infty$.

Comment: I think the first part of your answer can be simplified by using the following 
$$|f(n)-\hat{f}(n)|\leq d_{TV}(Bin(n,p), Poisson(np)) < p$$
where $d_{TV}$ denotes the total Variation distance. 

then we have $f(n)\leq \hat{f}(n)+O(p)$ and thus with your bounds $$f(n)\leq \frac{(np)^k}{k!} \frac{1}{1-np}+O(p)=\frac{(np)^k}{k!} (1+\frac{np}{1-np})+O(p)$$ 

But as we only have $np < 1$ we have that $\frac{np}{1-np}$ can be arbitrarily large..

Comment: Simplified? You mean, *weakened*... The distance in total variation is at most $np^2$ (this is exactly the result my answer uses) and $np^2\lt p$.

Comment: Oh ok, sorry. I see, my fault. If I try to get an estimate for your Approximation I get 
$$f(n) \leq \hat{f}(n)+O(np^2)\leq{(np)^k}{k!}\frac{1}{1−np}+O(np^2) \leq \frac{(np)^k}{k!}(1+\frac{np+O(k!n^{1-k}p^{2-k}(1-np))}{1−np})$$
but I don't see any Chance that I'll get the bound I'm looking for. Is this because my estimates are too weak or might using the estimate $g(n)\leq \frac{1}{1−np}$ be too weak, because this term can get arbitrarily large?

by the way: thank you for your help and linking the paper!

Comment: So I had a look at your answer again and again and tried to get some asymptotic bound out of it. But  don't see how I can get this, if I have $$e^{-np}\leq g(n)\leq \frac{1}{1-np}$$ because I don't know how $e^{-np}$ and $\frac{1}{1-np}$ are asymptotically related, as $e^{-np}\leq 1$ and $\frac{1}{1-np}$ is unbounded. 

It would be a big help if you could tell me, how to Change this in some asymptotics. 

What I did in the answer above won't help too much (or does it?) because it's an upper bound, but not the same asymptotic lower. 

So I am really really stuck here!

Comment: This "$1/(1-np)$ is unbounded" thing seems to obsess you but it is really not a problem. See Edit for one possible extension of the core computations.

Comment: Thank you! I'm sorry for still having a question..
Does that mean that $g(n)\in O(1-c(k)np)=O(1-np)$? And thus $f(n)=\frac{(np)^k}{k!}(1-O(np)+O(np^2))$?
Does it matter whether I write $+O(np)$ or $-O(np)$?
I don't want to be too concentrated on my goal solution above, but then, as $n^{-1} > np^2$ we would get $\frac{(np)^k}{k!}(1+O(np+n^{-1})$. 
How do I get $c(k)$? I see that $e^{-np}\geq 1-np$, but this doesn't help here?
$$c(k)=\frac{e^{-np}}{(1-np)(1-\frac{np}{k+1})},$$ but no idea how to get rid of $n$,$p$. For every hint I would be grateful! Sorry I couldn't do more on my own. I tried!

Comment: Well, well, well... This may be bluntly put, I must say there seems to be a gap between the techniques you master and the question you ask. Anyway, to compute some $c(k)$ is to exhibit some $c$ (**independent of $x$**, naturally) such that $\mathrm e^{-x}/(1-x/(k+1))\leqslant1-cx$ for every $x$ in $(0,1)$ (since $0\lt np\lt1$). Can you do that for some specific $k\geqslant1$, say $k=1$? What about $c=4$?

Comment: You removed some comments. Why?

Comment: I deleted it because I thought I found an answer, then wanted to post the answer and then found out that it doesn't work when writing. So I took a look at it again, and that's my solution now, but I think something went wrong... We look for a $c$ such that $cx \leq 1- \frac{e^{-x}}{1-\frac{x}{k+1}}$ thus for a $c$ such that $c \leq \frac{1}{x} - \frac{e^{-x}}{x-\frac{x^2}{k+1}}$. This term is minimal for Setting $\frac{1}{x} > 1$ and $-\frac{e^{-x}}{x-\frac{x^2}{k+1}} > -(k+1)$ (when we say that $e^{-x}<1$, $x>0$ and $\frac{x^2}{k+1}<\frac{1}{k+1}$). But this gives $c=k+2$ and this is wrong.